# Is Ubuntu Server Edition stable enough for commercial use?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

Our organization use CentOS as our product running platform. It's a server application with a web interface.

Now we are planning to install our product into a smaller hardware and add a local user interface for the device. So we can make our software looks like a hardware device and sell it with higher price.

The problem is the CentOS's software repository is locked 2 or 3 years ago. So most libraries are outdated. That's not a big problem for server applications as we use C language Runtime only.

But for writing a User Interface, I need to depend on more libraries and I have to install many libraries by hand. It's complicated and it's easy to make mistakes.

So I suggested to my colleagues, if we can try to switch to Ubuntu Server Edition to use new software repository. BUT, all of them are skeptical about Ubuntu's stability :

TWO Main Reason :

1. It's could not be as stable as RHEL or Slackware.
2. It's originated from desktop version. So it's stability is not proved, is skeptical.

I've been use Ubuntu desktop for a long time and I feels it's stable. But I don't have any evidence that the server version is stable enough.

Maybe I am biased because I am more familiar with Ubuntu. So I think your objective advice could help me to find out the truth.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/53954/centos-vs-ubuntu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some references for the [Ubuntu Server Edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatIsubuntu/serveredition).

> built on the solid foundation of Debian which is known for its robust server installations — has a strong heritage for reliable performance and predictable evolution.

1. [Ubuntu 9.04 Server Edition Certified on New HP ProLiant Servers](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Ubuntu-9-04-Server-Edition-Certified-on-New-HP-ProLiant-Servers-114456.shtml)

   > Ubuntu 9.04 Server Edition is now fully supported on the latest HP ProLiant G6 servers. In total, there are now 17 energy-efficient HP ProLiant configurations for which Canonical provides Ubuntu Server Edition support.

   - [Canonical’s management and monitoring software for Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/news/manage-ubuntu-server-in-amazon-ec2-cloud)
     now manages Ubuntu Server Edition on the Amazon EC2 cloud
   - [Ubuntu Server Edition 10.04 Lucid Lynx: Canonical’s ISV Priorities](http://www.workswithu.com/2009/09/21/ubuntu-server-edition-1004-lucid-lynx-canonicals-isv-priorities/)

     > Canonical in mid-2009 announced that Alfresco (open source content management) and Openbravo (open source ERP) both run on Ubuntu Server Edition.

---

Another [discussion](http://lxer.com/module/forums/t/29615/) on familiar lines.

Comment: One colleague just told me "you are just too proud to admit you are wrong when all other people oppose you".

Maybe he is right.

Answer (score 3):

I use Ubuntu server on all of my *nix servers. So my answer is a bit biased. However, 6 servers, running for 4 years in a row had 3 hours downtime in the past 12 months. 2 of those hours where intentionally, 1 hour was due to third party software bug.

Ubuntu = debian = stability. If you want to be sure. Just install the bare minimum of packages with TCP/IP stack and apt-get everyting you need... With redundant hardware, you cannot go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

[**Top Ubuntu Server Edition Deployments**](http://www.workswithu.com/the-works-with-u-1000/top-ubuntu-server-edition-deployments/)

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, no. Ubuntu Server is a horrible server operating system. Ubuntu staff are also obnoxious and abusive when errors are reported as well. It makes for a very unsatisfactory business solution.

Comment: Please back up your highly subjective claims by facts. Why is it "horrible"? What are examples of "obnoxious" and "abusive" behavior when reporting errors?